# Tk fileevent does not work with socket on Windows

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit

Lately I have been developing GUI applications on windows with perl and Tk. There are many annoying things in this environment that work fine in Linux. One of the most annoying is that fileevent does not appear to work. I have a Net::Telnet session that I pass to fileevent, in Linux it works fine, in windows, the callback never gets called. I have found several posts on perl monks discussing workarounds, I think involving polling, this is not desired. First off, does anyone know why this does not work? Select supports sockets in windows, I would suspect there are using select internally no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rap on Windows is that it's hard to implement *non-blocking* sockets.

In Unix you can invoke `$socket->blocking(0)` and that's all you have to do to make sure your socket reads won't block when there's no input to be read from them. In Windows, that doesn't work and you need to poll them to be sure there's something there before you read.

In addition to polling, the other workaround I've seen is to call `ioctl($socket,0x8004667e,1)` on your socket handle, where [0x8004667e](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=0x8004667e&oq=0x8004667e&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=s&gs_upl=0l0l0l2032l0l0l0l0l0l0l0l0ll0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=8a869f5766c153ac&biw=1202&bih=730) is a magic number to enable non-blocking behavior on Windows sockets. I've had mixed success with this and don't know what the unintended consequences might be applying it to a `Net::Telnet` socket.

Comment: [This script](http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/E/EM/EMMANUEL/socksproxy/socksproxy-0.02.pl), for example, has the `ioctl(...)` trick sprinkled throughout the code ... but then the script's author comments them all out, and goes with "Major modification of the IO::Socket::Socks" module.

Comment: (Tcl/)Tk doesn't use select() on Windows, in part because sockets aren't the only interesting kind of event producer; it uses a complex mix of low-level API and threads and message passing and … it makes me sick to think about all the details _but it works_.